# Extrair parte decimal de um Decimal

Tags: c#, .net, algoritmo, decimal

Estou com problemas para formular um bom meio de extrair a parte decimal de uma variável `decimal`, até o momento a implementação existente no sistema é esta:

```
public static bool getCasasDecimais(decimal val, out int result)
{
    string[] split = val.ToString().Split('.');
    return int.TryParse(split[split.Length-1], out result);
}
```

Mas a mesma tem um problema, é preciso adaptar o código dependendo da cultura em que está rodando o programa por conta da divisão do número pelo ponto decimal.

Estou tentando encontrar alguma outra implementação para retirar essa parte do número, de preferência algo que não manipule uma `string` para realizar tal operação. <s>A unica forma que me veio a mente foi utilizando `Truncate`:</s>

```
decimal number = 12.5523;
var x = number - Math.Truncate(number);
```

Mas por algum motivo, essa implementação não me parece muito robusta, não sei realmente explicar o por que, mas gostaria de ver outras implementações possíveis antes de decidir qual utilizarei.

Após um comentário do user [dcastro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/2360/dcastro) na pergunta, resolvi testar novamente a implementação especificada acima e a mesma não retorna o valor esperado, visto que eu desejo ter os dígitos decimais em um inteiro, e não apenas a parte decimal.

```
Exemplo: 45.545    
Resultado esperado: 545
Resultado proveniente da implementação com Math.Truncate: 0.545
```

A dúvida continua, existe uma forma de receber esse valor sem manipular o número como `string`?

Comment: Se o input for `123.456`, queres que o resultado seja `456` ou `0.456`?

Comment: o resultado esperado é `456`, e testando agora a implementação utilizando o `Truncate` sequer funcionará, pois irá retornar `0.456`

Comment: Pois :/ Acho que o melhor mesmo é usar a cultura invariante.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É possível obter a parte decimal como um número inteiro da forma que você espera, sem utilizar Strings, utilizando o `Math.Floor` da seguinte maneira: contando quantas casas decimais há no número resultante e multiplicando a parte decimal pela potência da quantidade de casas:

```
public static void Main()
{
    decimal numero = 45.545M;
    int parteDecimal = ObterCasasDecimais(numero);
    Console.WriteLine(parteDecimal); // resulta 545
}

static int ObterCasasDecimais(decimal numero) 
{    
    decimal resultado = numero - Math.Floor(numero);
    int qtdCasas = QuantidadeCasasDecimais(resultado);
    int parteDecimal = Convert.ToInt32((double)resultado * Math.Pow(10, qtdCasas));
    return parteDecimal;
}

static int QuantidadeCasasDecimais(decimal num)
{
    return BitConverter.GetBytes(decimal.GetBits(num)[3])[2];
}
```

Veja o código funcionando [Nesse .Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KoR9NR)

### Desempenho:

Fiz alguns testes de performance utilizando o seu método atual (com Strings) e o método que propus (utilizando Floor) e concluí que quando chamada apenas uma vez, ou em um loop com poucas iterações, o método com string é mais rápido. Quando há muitas iterações, o método Floor apresenta um desempenho superior. Na prática, se forem chamados apenas uma vez e não dentro de loops, a diferença é irrisória então use o método que achar mais conveniente.

O código que usei para testar foi mais ou menos esse:

```
int TotalNumeros = 1000;
decimal[] decimais =
{
    2.50M, 3.2345M, 54.4004M, 32.1212M, 123123.3244325M, 3112.453M, 1.2M, 43.12M, 9994.2342M, 24324.2M, 5345.0M, 3123.00M, 123134.456456M
};

Random random = new Random();
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
stopwatch.Start();
for (int i = 0; i < TotalNumeros; i++)
{
    decimal number = decimais[random.Next(decimais.Length - 1)]; // pega um número aleatório do array de decimais
    int resultado = ObterCasasDecimais(number); // Método proposto para resposta (Floor)
}
stopwatch.Stop();
TimeSpan resultadoFloor = stopwatch.Elapsed;

stopwatch.Reset();
stopwatch.Start();
for (int i = 0; i < TotalNumeros; i++)
{ 
    decimal number = decimais[random.Next(decimais.Length - 1)];// pega um número aleatório do array de decimais 
    int resultado;
    getCasasDecimais(number, out resultado); // método atual (String)
}
stopwatch.Stop();
TimeSpan resultadoMetodoAtual = stopwatch.Elapsed;

Console.WriteLine(resultadoFloor < resultadoMetodoAtual ? "Método Floor melhor" : "Método atual melhor");

Console.WriteLine("\r\nResultado Floor: {0:g}", resultadoFloor);
Console.WriteLine("Resultado Método Atual: {0:g}", resultadoMetodoAtual);
```

Answer (score 5):

Existe outra forma, inclusive mais eficiente, para alcançar o mesmo resultado.

A resposta aceita não funciona com números negativos e poderia ser mais eficiente usando alocação na pilha para não por pressão no GC. Se melhorar e eficiência com [`Span`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.getbits?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397#system-decimal-getbits(system-decimal-system-span((system-int32)))) e resolver o problema do negativo, pode ser uma boa opção, especialmente em versões mais antigas (a maioria não consegue ser eficiente).

As outras respostas também não funcionam em todas as situações, ou é ineficiente alocando memória sem necessidade, dá para resolver só com matemática. Soluções com `string` são atrocidades.

A minha forma não tem problema de cultura, até porque o seu uso é conceitualmente errado. Ela não consegue lidar quando tem uma quantidade muito grande de casas decimais, imagino que não cairá em algo com tantas casas, mas deveria pelo menos dar erro mais específico. Só funciona no .NET 7 para frente porque usei o none [`Scale`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.scale?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Note que eu não tratei de forma diferente se tiver zero à direita (não significativo), como a resposta aceita não tratou.

```
using static System.Console;
using static System.Decimal;

WriteLine(GetDecimalPart(45.545M));
WriteLine(GetDecimalPart(45.54M));
WriteLine(GetDecimalPart(0.545M));
WriteLine(GetDecimalPart(-45.545M));
WriteLine(GetDecimalPart(45.5450M));
WriteLine(GetDecimalPart(999988776655.443322116M));

static int GetDecimalPart(decimal value) => (int)((Abs(value) - Floor(Abs(value))) * (decimal)System.Math.Pow(10, value.Scale));
```

Veja [funcionando no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1592Cm). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Decimal/GetDecimalPart.cs).

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/pY2vkR) para versões anteriores, que pode parecer uma solução pior, mas usar `Pow()`, ou mesmo `Log()` pode ser até mais ineficiente de tão complexa que são essas funções.

Answer (score 2):

Eu encontrei uma solução simples e eficiente:

1. Remove a parte inteira e converte o resultado em string: `Math.Abs((decimal)numero) % 1`
2. Remove o "0." do resultado: `Substring(2)`
3. Converte a string resultante num Int32: `Convert.ToInt32`

O Código final fica assim:

```
decimal numero = 123.5489m;
int fracao = Convert.ToInt32((Math.Abs(numero) % 1).ToString().Substring(2));
Console.WriteLine("Fracao: " + fracao);
```

Código original retirado [daqui](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/C_Sharp/Q_23653576.html).

Answer (score 0):

Bem, a maneira mais simples de resolver o problema da cultura é usar a `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`. Assim o bom funcionamento do código já não depende da maquina onde corre.

```
val.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: Na utilização dessa solução, qual o digito separador de decimal que será usado? `'.'` ou `','` ?

Comment: Infelizmente a `Math.Truncate` não retorna o que eu desejo, então ela não é a solução ;/

Comment: É `.`, então o `Split` não precisa de ser alterado.

Answer (score 0):

Tente o seguinte:
    float x = 1.466;
    string nu = (Mathf.Abs (x) % 1).ToString("N1").Substring(2);
    int milissegundos = System.Convert.ToInt32 (nu);

SAIDA: 4
onde: N1 - formata em uma casa decimal, N2 -duas...
Substring remove "1.";

Não é a melhor pratica mais é a que resolve num contador de tempo para obter os milissegundos.

Answer (score -2):

Para o meu caso, isso foi suficiente:

```
double valor = 321654987369.43;
  int valorInteiro = valor ~/ 1; // parte inteira da divisão por 1
  int valorCentavo = ((valor % 1) * 100).round();
```

Answer (score -3):

Deixando uma opção diferente das que li por aqui.
Acredito que dispensa comentários para o entendimento

var result = valorDecimal - Math.Truncate(valorDecimal)

Comment: Mas assim não retorna um número 0,alguma coisa?

Comment: Retornará zero nos seguintes casos:

Exemplo 1)
0,00 = 5,00 - 5,00

Exemplo 2) aqui retornará apenas as casas decimais
0,26 = 5,26 - 5,00

Comment: Exatamente. O que é pedido é "Exemplo: **45.545** Resultado esperado: **545**" e não 0.545